# Loss of precision calculating degrees from two points

Tags: java

I have made a class Location which allows to set, change a location (coordinates x,y , the limits are decided by xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax), to caluculate the distance between two points, and to get the direction from another location.
The direction is in degress (in [0,2pi]) from another location.
The direction goes from North (assuming that North is the pole oriented where there are higher coordinates), in clockwise order.

```
package TruckingCompany;

public class Location 
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private static final double xMax=1000.0;
    private static final double xMin=-1000.0;
    private static final double yMax=1000.0;
    private static final double yMin=-1000.0;
    public Location()
    {
        setX(0.0);
        setY(0.0);
    }
    public Location(double x,double y)
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }
    public Location(Location location)
    {
        setX(location.getX());
        setY(location.getY());
    }
    public void setX(double x)
    {
        if(x>=xMin && x<=xMax)
        this.x=x;
    }
    public void setY(double y)
    {
        if(y>=yMin && y<=yMax)
            this.y=y;
    }
    public void set(double x,double y)
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }
    public double getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public double getDistanceFrom(Location from)
    {
        double dx,dy;
        dx=from.getX()-x;
        dy=from.getY()-y;
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2.0)+Math.pow(dy, 2.0));
    }
    public double getDirectionFrom(Location from)
    {
        double dy=from.getY()-y;
        double direction=Math.PI/4 - Math.asin  (Math.toRadians(dy/getDistanceFrom(from)));
        if(Double.isNaN(direction)==false)
        {
            if(from.getX()-x<0.0)
            direction+=Math.PI/2;
             if(dy<0.0)
                direction+=Math.PI;
        }
        return direction;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "(" + x + " , " + y + ")";
    }
}
```

The problem is the the precision, for example I try to calculate the distance from these two locations:

```
Location l1,l2;
l1=new Location(0.0,0.0);
l2=new Location(300.0,300.0);
System.out.print(Math.toDegrees(l1.getDirectionFrom(l2)));
```

The problem is the precision: in this example it prints 44.29 degrees, it should be 45.0, why a so huge loss of precision?

Comment: Side note: Can't you just use `Math.atan2()`?

Comment: Do you get the expected results for 0,0->0,300 and 0,0->300,0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're near 45 degrees, which means you're going to be operating close to maxima and minima for some trig functions.  I'd check the steps and see if you're getting an intermediate result very close to 0.

- Try replacing the call to pow with `dx*dx` and `dy*dy`.
- Break this up with intermediate results.

Comment: Yay! I got a numerical question!  Take that my numerical analysis professors! :-)

Comment: Why replacing pow with dx*dx, isn't that the same?

Comment: No, not usually, because pow has to be able to handle any combination of floats, like pow(3.14159,2.71828).  *Mathematically* they appear the same; the actual computation probably involves something like taking log of the arguments, and opens you up to loss of precision.

Comment: Aren't argument's bits copied identical? Maybe an extra multiplication could make the difference.

Comment: Ramy, it's not the copied bits, it's how the exponent is computed.  dx*dx is one multiply.  General exponentiation is going to be something like (exp((ln x)*(ln x)) with various sorts of numerical magic in all three function calls.  Now, I don't *know*  that was a factor in this case, but I'm pretty certain it's both slower and less precise.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY)` to calculate the angle of a vector in radians.  It returns answers all the way from `0` to `2 * Math.PI` without having to do casework depending on the signs of the inputs.